# What happened to to phpMyAdmin's "display direction" dropdown list in version 4?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I recently upgraded from phpMyAdmin 3 to 4.  The "Display Direction" option has disappeared.  This is the option on query results pages that allows you to control if result sets are displayed one per row (horizontal) or one per column (vertical).

I see that there is still a configuration option to set the "default display direction":
http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_DefaultDisplay

However, I want to be able to change the direction on a per-query-result basis, like I was able to in v3.  Is there a way to re-enable this feature?  I've searched through the docs and have not found anything.

-Josh

Comment: I m interested to find out why you are using PMA? which features keep you using it? Compared to http://topnew.net/sidu ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the 4th phpMyAdmin there is a new settings option "Show display direction". It's responsible for enabling or disabling ability to switch display directions in a per-query-result basis.

By default, this is unchecked (disabled).

You can find this setting in: *Settings > Main panel > Browser mode > "Show display direction"*.

Comment: For others that might cross this answer, know that the [show display direction feature](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1636/) has been removed as of PMA version 4.4.